# Simulate multiple Post request

Tags: testing, load, fiddler, load-testing, stress-testing

I have to simulate multiple Post requests, each post requests takes 3 parameters, first 2 are the documents we have to merge together and 3rd is the location where they will be placed, so the value is of type File.

I have to do the load test for this and want to simulate say 1000 concurrent requests.

Initially I was using Fiddler for this but when I make a request with Fiddler open, then the request takes bit longer to finish and hence most of them fails with error 504. However, if I make a request when Fiddler is not open then the request completed instantly. Very weird.

But can anybody suggest me other tools where I could simulate multiple post requests taking in file parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Gatling](http://gatling.io/). I used it and did not see any limitation in the type of POST request you can perform in the script, so you should be able to have your file parameter.